# Show Info bubble when clicking on a Marker in HERE Maps + REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, here-api

So I'm currently developing a map-based application using React and HERE maps. I'm using the boilerplate in the documentation using Hooks. I'm firstly fetching the events and then displaying them in the useEffectLayout() hook, where the map loads.

```
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import useWindow from '../../CustomHooks/GetWindowSize/getSize';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/Search';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getEvents} from '../../actions/UserActions';
const HEREmap = ({userLocation, posts}) => {

    const mapRef = React.useRef(null);
    const size = useWindow();

     //this is the method to add the marker to the map
     const addEventsToMap = (events, H, hMap, ui) =>{
         let markers = [];
         events.map((el)=>{
           var icon = new H.map.DomIcon(svgMarkup),
           coords = {lat: el.Latitude, lng: el.Longitude},
           marker = new H.map.DomMarker(coords, {icon: icon});
          hMap.addObject(marker);
         })
     }
     
    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  
      if (!mapRef.current) return;

      const H = window.H;
      const platform = new H.service.Platform({
          apikey: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`,
          app_id: "XXXXXX"
      });

      const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

      const hMap = new H.Map(mapRef.current, defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
        center: { lat:userLocation.lat, lng: userLocation.lgn},
        zoom: 13,
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
      });

    //this add the user's location as a marker on the map

    var icon = new H.map.DomIcon(svgMarkup),
    coords = {lat: userLocation.lat, lng: userLocation.lgn},
    marker = new H.map.DomMarker(coords, {icon: icon});

    hMap.addObject(marker);
    
      
    const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(hMap));
  
      const ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(hMap, defaultLayers);
      
      //this method gets called with the fetched events
      addEventsToMap(posts, H, hMap, ui);

      return () => {
        hMap.dispose();
      };
    }, [mapRef]);

    return (
        <div className="map" ref={mapRef} style={{ height: size.height/1.5}}>
       
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  userA:state.userA  
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getEvents})(HEREmap);
```

I've read the documentation and it says to attach an onClick listener to the icon when it's created, but how do I add the info bubble to the same icon, when I need the reference to the `ui` as well as the information for each event?

Is there a more effective way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a React user, but I'd make the `ui` object available to your entire function, or the same scope as your map object. Does that help at all?

Comment: Hey @Raymond Camden, thanks for your suggestion. In the end, I found another solution! :)

Comment: @TonislavTachev I am trying to achieve something similar. How did you go about it?